# Como fazer cálculo com 3 variáveis do tipo DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, data, timespan

Eu tenho essas 4 variáveis:

```
public System.DateTime TempoOtimista { get; set; }
public System.DateTime TempoProvavel { get; set; }
public System.DateTime TempoPessimista { get; set; }
public System.DateTime TempoRevisado { get; set; }

TempoRevisado =  (TempoOtimista  + TempoProvavel + TempoPessimista) / 3;
```

Como faço este cálculo?

Comment: Resolveu o problema? Precisa de mais alguma explicação?

Comment: @bigown Você foi muito claro, mas no meu caso a melhor opção seria o uso do tipo **DateTime** . Meu projeto ficou assim:

`var otimista = (atividade.TempoOtimista - atividade.Inicio).TotalDays;
            var provavel = (atividade.TempoProvavel - atividade.Inicio).TotalDays;
            var pessimista = (atividade.TempoPessimista - atividade.Inicio).TotalDays;`

Comment: Você pode continuar usando ela, mas não é a melhor opção, ela é errada. E o que você fez não soluciona o que você descreveu na pergunta. Você está falando de algo completamente diferente do que foi descrito.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 8):

Assim:

```
public TimeSpan TempoOtimista { get; set; }
public TimeSpan TempoProvavel { get; set; }
public TimeSpan TempoPessimista { get; set; }
public TimeSpan TempoRevisado { get; set; }

TempoRevisado = new TimeSpan(0, 0,
                (int)(TempoOtimista + TempoProvavel + TempoPessimista).TotalSeconds / 3);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ORrrNb). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UHKFvT). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/CalcTime.cs).

Você pode dizer que eu mudei o tipo. Mas agora está certo. `DateTime` marca um ponto no tempo, não marca um tempo dispendido. Isto está completamente errado. Com dados errados, você só pode obter resultados errados. Então a primeira coisa para consertar é trocar o tipo para guardar um intervalo de tempo com [`TimeSpan`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Só podemos fazer a conta do jeito certo. Até daria para fazer a conta usando o jeito errado, mas quando se conceitua errado, mais cedo ou mais tarde terá problemas.

Em algum momento tive que pegar a quantidade de segundos porque o `TimeSpan` não permite fazer divisão.